# ASP.Net C# - ignoring phone keyboard Enter button on form

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile

I'm doing a mobile version of an existing ASP.Net site, just re-doing the layouts to make it mobile friendly, not making a web app or anything.  I have a textbox where people can enter some optional text, but if you hit enter on the on-screen keyboard it's firing a button which I don't want to happen.

I've tried setting up a panel with a default button, but it's not working on the Android phone I'm trying it on:

```
<asp:Panel id="wrapper" runat="server" DefaultButton="decoy">
...
    <asp:Button ID="addtobasket" runat="server" oncommand="a2b_Command" Text="Add to basket" class="addtobasket uppercase" />
    <asp:Button ID="decoy" runat="server" Visible="false" />
...
</asp:Panel>
```

Is it the fact that I'm having to hide the decoy button?  It still fires a postback when you click the enter key if it's not hidden, so is there a straightforward way of preventing this?  I just need the keyboard to close.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable/dont set the default button all together if you are on a mobile browser?

Comment: I need the button on the page to work if you press it as it's an "add to basket" button - what I don't want is the button to be triggered by the phone keyboard enter button after you've just typed something into a textbox.

Comment: This actually led me to the answer - I disabled the decoy button, and hid it using styles rather than making it hidden (1 pixel, same colour as background).  This let me point the default button at it, which works as I wanted.  Thanks!!